# Javascript callback function in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write a callback function with js here. The problem is that the returned value is incorrect. The variable "d" in the ajax call contains the right data. But the variable a in the done(..) function, does not. Does anyone know how to assign a the value of d?

```
    function render_confirmation_email(data, cart, delivery_date){
        console.log("Render confirmation email")
        var purchaseTable = "<table>"
        for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var concept = cart[i].name;
            var price = cart[i].price;
            purchaseTable += "<tr>"
            purchaseTable += "<td>" + concept + " - </td>"
            purchaseTable += "</tr>"
            purchaseTable += "<tr>"
            purchaseTable += "<td>" + price + " kr\n</td>"
            purchaseTable += "</tr>"
        }

        purchaseTable += "</table>"
        purchaseTable += "<br> <p>It will be delivered on " + delivery_date + "</p>"

        var tempDom;
        tempDom = $('<div></div>').append(data);
        tempDom.find('#purchaseTable').append(purchaseTable);
        return tempDom.text()
    }


    function get_confirmation_email(cart, delivery_date, render_confirmation_email) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"/confirmation_email",
            async: false,
            success:function(data) {
                console.log("success");
                // render_confirmation_email called when data is ready
                var d = (render_confirmation_email(data, cart, delivery_date));
                console.log("Rendering done")
                console.log(d)
                return d
            }
        });
    }

    var a = get_confirmation_email(JSONcart, form.querySelector('input[name=deliverydate]').value, render_confirmation_email);
    a.done(function(data) {
        console.log("Function done");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should really not use `async: false`

Comment: Noted and removed :) It was left there from a failed try to solve my issue.

Comment: `return` does nothing in `success`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `then()` for each instance. A `return` does nothing in `success` as it is not part of the promise chain

Basic example

```
function doAjax() {
  // sample data that will be returned
  var json = '{"foo":[1,2,3]}'

  return $.ajax({...}).then(function(resp){
     // return to next "then()" in promise chain 
     return resp.foo
  })
}


doAjax().then(function(data){
  console.log(data) // [1,2,3]
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhag5scn/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `d`.

```
var a = get_confirmation_email(JSONcart,form.querySelector('input[name=deliverydate]').value, render_confirmation_email);
```

You don't have to use `a.done()`;

`a` should have the data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate.

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'include/ajax.php',
        data: { action: 'functionname', value:value },
        beforeSend:function(){

        },
        success:function(data){


        },
        error:function(){


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`jqXHR.done()` is a promised callback getting the **response data** passed as argument. You can use it as replacement of `success` option.

```
var a = get_confirmation_email(JSONcart, form.querySelector('input[name=deliverydate]').value, render_confirmation_email);
a.done(function(data) {
    var d = (render_confirmation_email(data, cart, delivery_date));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can pass a done callback to the get_confirmation_email function and get the data.

example:

```
function get_confirmation_email(cart, delivery_date, render_confirmation_email,done) {

    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/confirmation_email",
        async: false,
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            // render_confirmation_email called when data is ready
            var d = (render_confirmation_email(data, cart, delivery_date));
            console.log("Rendering done")
            console.log(d)
            done(d);
        }
    });
}

get_confirmation_email(JSONcart, form.querySelector('input[name=deliverydate]').value, render_confirmation_email,function(data) {
    console.log("Function done");
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think function get done callback

```
function get_confirmation_email(cart, delivery_date, render_confirmation_email,done_callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/confirmation_email",
        async: false,
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            // render_confirmation_email called when data is ready
            var d = (render_confirmation_email(data, cart, delivery_date));
            console.log("Rendering done")
            console.log(d)
            return d
        },
       complete : function(){
            if(typeof done_callback === "function") done_callback();
       }
    })
}
```

and
function have many arguments. So you change arguments to obj.
like below
{
  cart : ""
  delivery_date : "",
  .....
}

Answer (score 0):

```
function render_confirmation_email(data, cart, delivery_date) {
console.log("Render confirmation email")
var purchaseTable = "<table>"
var tempDom;
tempDom = $('<div></div>').append(data);
tempDom.find('#purchaseTable').append(purchaseTable);
return tempDom.html()
}


function get_confirmation_email(cart, delivery_date, render_confirmation_email) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/confirmation_email",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    }).then(function(resp) {
        return render_confirmation_email(resp, cart, delivery_date)
    });
}

var a = get_confirmation_email(JSONcart, form.querySelector('input[name=deliverydate]').value, render_confirmation_email);
        a.done(function(datababy) {
            // data contains the email
            console.log("Function done");
            console.log(datababy);
        });
```

I ended up with this. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer: .then()